# Simple console application to practice OOP and file layout

Tags: c++, object-oriented, console

I am not used to work with OOP so I decided to make a simple console "walk" game to focus on the OOP and the general game design process. I tried to make it as robust as possible but I feel like I could have build the hierarchy of the classes and functions in a more systematic way. Please think of this as a much larger project. I would appreciate if you could criticize and offer a more reliable way of ordering the objects and of course other mistakes and performance issues.

### Coordinate.hpp

```
#ifndef COORD_H
#define COORD_H
struct Coordinate{
    int x;
    int y;
};
#endif
```

### Game.hpp

```
//Clear the console for different operating systems 
#ifdef _WIN32
#define CLEAR "cls"
#else
#define CLEAR "clear"
#endif

#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Map.hpp"
class Game{
public:
    Game();
private:
    void setup();
    void loop(Player p, Map m);
    char processInput(Player p);
    void update(Player &p, char movement, Map m);
    void draw(Player p, Map m);
    void clear();
};
#endif
```

### Map.hpp

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Map{
public:
    Map(int h, int w);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
    std::vector<std::string> getLevel();
private:
    std::vector<std::string> level; 
    int width;
    int height;
    void initMap(int h, int w);
};
#endif
```

### Player.hpp

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Coordinate.hpp"
#include "Map.hpp"
class Player{
public:
    Player();
    void movePlayer(int x, int y, Map m);
    Coordinate getCoord();
private:
    Coordinate coord;
};
#endif
```

### Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.hpp"
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Map.hpp"

Game::Game(){
    setup();
}
void Game::setup(){
    Player p;
    Map m(5, 5);
    Game::loop(p, m);
}
//Main Game Loop
/*
Clear the screen
Draw the map
Take input
Update the Map
*/
void Game::loop(Player p, Map m){
    while(true){
        Game::clear();
        Game::draw(p, m);
        char movement = Game::processInput(p);
        Game::update(p, movement, m);
    }
}
char Game::processInput(Player p){
    char movement;
    std::cin>>movement;
    tolower(movement);
    return movement;
}
void Game::update(Player &p, char movement, Map m){
    switch (movement)
    {
    case 'w'://up
        p.movePlayer(0,-1,m);
        break;
    case 'a'://left
        p.movePlayer(-1,0,m);
        break;
    case 's'://down
        p.movePlayer(0,1,m);
        break;
    case 'd'://right
        p.movePlayer(1,0,m);
        break;    
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void Game::draw(Player p, Map m){

    Map map = m;//Copy the layer without the player without changing the main level

    std::vector<std::string> level = map.getLevel();
    level[p.getCoord().y].replace(p.getCoord().x, 1, "P");//replace the # with P

    for(int i=0; i<map.getHeight(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<map.getWidth(); j++){
            std::cout<<level[i][j];
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

void Game::clear(){
    system(CLEAR);//works for Windows and Linux
}
```

### Map.cpp

```
#include "Map.hpp"

Map::Map(int h, int w){
    initMap(h, w);
}

int Map::getWidth(){
    return width;
}
int Map::getHeight(){
    return height;
}

std::vector<std::string> Map::getLevel(){
    return level;
}

void Map::initMap(int h, int w){
    height = h;
    width = w;
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        std::string str;
        level.push_back(str);
        for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
            level[i].append(".");
        }
    }
}
```

### Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Map.hpp"

Player::Player(){
    coord.x=0;
    coord.y=0;
}
void Player::movePlayer(int x, int y, Map m){
    if(!(coord.x + x >= m.getWidth() || coord.x + x < 0)){//If not at the map limit, move
        coord.x += x;
    }
    if(!(coord.y + y >= m.getHeight() || coord.y + y < 0)){
        coord.y += y;
    }
}
Coordinate Player::getCoord(){
    return coord;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
/*ASCII Walk Simulator

P: Player
.: Walkable Path

Enter w,a,s,d to walk
*/
#include "Game.hpp"
int main(){
    Game game;
}
```

### In terminal:

```
g++ *.cpp -o out
```

Comment: Keep it up!  Writing self-learning projects like this is how _good_ programmers are made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't use `system("cls")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you have attempted to address.  The second is that it's a security hole.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example, if your terminal supports [ANSI Escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you could use this:

```
void cls()
{
    std::cout << "\x1b[2J";
}
```

### Use `const` where practical

I would not expect the `getWidth` or `getHeight` member functions of `Map` to alter the underlying map on which they operate, and indeed they do not.  You should make this expectation explicit by using the `const` keyword:

```
int Map::getWidth() const {
    return width;
}
```

### Pass by const reference where practical

The third argument to `Player::movePlayer` is a `Map` but that causes the entire map to be duplicated.  Better would be to make it `const Map &` because it is not modified and it doesn't need to be duplicated.

### Use standard functions where appropriate

The current `Player::movePlayer()` function is this (with the modification mentioned above):

```
void Player::movePlayer(int x, int y, const Map &m){
    if(!(coord.x + x >= m.getWidth() || coord.x + x < 0)){//If not at the map limit, move
        coord.x += x;
    }
    if(!(coord.y + y >= m.getHeight() || coord.y + y < 0)){
        coord.y += y;
    }
}
```

This is much easier to write using [`std::clamp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp):

```
void Player::movePlayer(int x, int y, const Map &m){
    coord.x = std::clamp(coord.x + x, 0, m.getWidth());
    coord.y = std::clamp(coord.y + y, 0, m.getHeight());
}
```

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The constructor for `Player` is this:

```
Player::Player(){
    coord.x=0;
    coord.y=0;
}
```

Better would be to simply have a default constructor for the `Coordinate` and then you could omit the `Player` constructor and simply have the compiler write one.

```
struct Coordinate{
    int x{0};
    int y{0};
};
```

See [C.48](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-in-class-initializer) for details.

### Fix the bug

The `Game::processInput` has a few bugs in it.  First, it passes `Player p` which is not used and should therefore not be passed.  Second, it has these lines:

```
char movement;
std::cin>>movement;
tolower(movement);
return movement;
```

The `tolower` has no effect here.  What you probably intended was this:

```
return tolower(movement);
```

The name is also not good.  It isn't really processing the input, only getting it from the user.

### Rethink the interface

The `Game` constructor doesn't just create the game but also runs it and never returns.  Consequently, `main` looks like this:

```
int main(){
    Game game;
}
```

A human reader would likely wonder why a `game` object is created and never used.  Better would be to have separate public functions: the constructor should *just* construct the object, and the `loop` (or perhaps `play()`) with a possibly separate check for end of game function.

A revised version of `Game.hpp` is this:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Map.hpp"
class Game{
public:
    bool play();
    void draw() const;
private:
    Player p;
    Map m{5, 5};
};
#endif
```

Now `main` is this:

```
int main(){
    Game game;
    do {
        game.draw();
    } while (game.play());
}
```

### Think of the user

I know this is just a preliminary study, but there is no way to exit the program gracefully.  That's an easy fix.  I rewrote and renamed your `update` like this:

```
bool Game::play() {
    bool playing{true};
    char movement;
    std::cin >> movement;
    switch (tolower(movement))
    {
    case 'w'://up
        p.movePlayer(0,-1,m);
        break;
    case 'a'://left
        p.movePlayer(-1,0,m);
        break;
    case 's'://down
        p.movePlayer(0,1,m);
        break;
    case 'd'://right
        p.movePlayer(1,0,m);
        break;
    case 'x': // exit
        playing = false;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return playing;
}
```

### Simplify your constructors

There is no reason for the `Map` constructor to call `initMap`.  Instead the functionality of `initMap` should be incorporated into the constructor directly.  Further, rather than stepping through every character, you can use `std::vector` and `std::string` constructor forms which take a count and a value.

```
Map::Map(std::size_t h, std::size_t w)
    : width{w}
    , height{h}
    , level{height, std::string(width, '.')}
{
}
```

Note that I've also converted `width` and `height` to `std::size_t` type.  There would be little sense in specifying a negative value for either.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the points Edward noted,

Your `#include` guard names are too simple.  In a real program, they might very easily clash with things from other libraries.  If you're writing for yourself, just use `#pragma once`.  If you use portable guards, don't use a simple word like that!  Always use a globally unique symbol; e.g. based on a UUID.

---

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

Write this down on a small card and stick it next to your monitor:

> **C++ has value semantics**

If you pass a complex class object, like `vector` or your own classes, you *copy* it!  Normally pass such things by `const &`.

---

```
void Game::loop(Player p, Map m){
    while(true){
        Game::clear();
        Game::draw(p, m);
        char movement = Game::processInput(p);
        Game::update(p, movement, m);
    }
}
```

If you are in the member function of `Game`, why are you qualifying all your calls with `Game::`?  That is the normal scope you are working in!  At best, this is not necessary and makes readers wonder what's happening that's not normal.

---

The `Game` class has no state.  Would it make sense to put the `Map` and the player objects as part of that Game?  Consider what it would take to have multiple instances of `Game` in existence at the same time.